# Existence of an element from a quotient space

Tags: quotient-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex inner product space and $U\subset V$ , a subspace of $V$ and $v \in V $, then it exists a unambiguous $w \in v + U$, such that $$\Vert w\Vert= min\{\Vert v'\Vert : v' \in v+U\}$$
While I know that this $w$ is (probably?) induced by the quotient space $V/U$ ,I have trouble understanding how to proceed.

Comment: The problem appears to be missing some information: after $V$ is given and $U \subset V$ is given, it appears that $v \in V$ should also be given before the problem can make sense.

Comment: The name "unitary space" is in [disuse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182065/571433).

Comment: **Hint:** Let $u_0$ be the orthogonal projection of $v$ to $U$ and set $w:=v-u_0$ that satisfies $w\perp U$, and use the Pythagorean theorem (if $w\perp u$ then $\|w+u\|^2=\|w\|^2+\|u\|^2$).